# Excel sort and filter protected cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros, sorting

I have a table where many columns are formulas that I don't want users to overtype with values, so I have protected the sheet and unlocked the cells they are allowed to edit. However the user needs to be able to sort and filter the table. From what I have read I don't think this is possible so I think I will need to write macros that unprotects the sheet, then allows the user to enter the sort or filter criteria, then performs the sort or filter, then protects the sheet again. Any guidance on how to write the macro (or how else to approach the problem) gratefully received. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on “Record Macro”.
2. Do (manually) what you want the macro to do.
3. Click on “Stop Recording”.
4. (If necessary) edit the macro.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the problem with this is that when you replay the macro it doesn't pause to allow the user to choose their sort or filer options and then complete the task. It simply repeats whatever choices you made when you recorded the macro.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted one macro to unprotect the sheet and a second to reprotect it. I guess if you don’t trust the user, you don’t trust the user, and what you’re asking for here makes more sense.  It will also be more difficult.  I’ll think about it.